# Is there a way to create a unique access link to a private Shopify store?

Tags: web, shopify

We have a list of 500 people that we would like to invite to an early pre-order of our product. Is there a way to limit access to our store to only those invited? We would like to be able to track who accessed the store, and who did not.

We could simply set a standard password for the whole store, however, we wouldn't be able to track unique visitors if we went that route.

We are using the Dawn theme.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a Shopify App called Locksmith.

Answer (score -2):

There exist a million ways to do this. One is to ensure the product is only visible to logged in customers. No random Joe Blow public can see this special pre-order product. Only a logged in customer. Send an email to these 500 people, inviting them to view the product. First they login, then they see the product. Protect the product itself by checking the customer info. If they have a tag of "I am big swinging pickle", then you assume they are of your 500 special customers, because you also tagged them. There you go. Simple recipe. Have fun.